# DBIx::Class (Perl ORM) equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, perl, eloquent, dbix-class

We started our web-based app back in 2012 when Perl was still popular. Now we want to reimplement it in PHP, preferably Laravel. However, I miss the power of DBIx::Class in their default ORM, Eloquent, and the alternative, Doctrine, from reading the docs seems more complicated, but doesn't solve the issue either. What I use DBIx::Class for:

- Regenerate model classes from reading the DB structure, preserving any code that has been added to them (should have).
- Generate complex queries (incl. nested joins, subqueries) from pure language constructs, no SQL needed (must have).

Code sample:

```
rows => $rows,
page => $page,
'select' => [
        'entity_id',
        { group_concat => [ { distinct => 'pictures.id' } ], -as => 'photos' },
        { '' => [ 'entity.name' ], -as => 'entity_name' },
        { '' => [ 'municipality.name' ], -as => 'municipality_name' },
        { '' => [ 'me.birth_date' ], -as => 'bd' },
        { concat => [ { date_format => [ 'me.birth_date', \$c->config->{dateFormat} ] }, \"' ('", { timestampdiff => [ \'YEAR', 'me.birth_date', \'CURDATE()' ] }, \"')'" ], -as
        { date_format => [ 'me.birth_date', \$c->config->{dateFormat} ], -as => 'bd1' },
        { timestampdiff => [ \'YEAR', 'me.birth_date', \'CURDATE()' ], -as => 'bd2' },
        { '' => [ 'entity_state_type.name' ], -as => 'entity_state_name' },
        { '' => [ 'data_list_item.name' ], -as => 'entity_state_reason_name' },
        { '' => [ 'entity_state.note_text' ], -as => 'entity_state_note' },
        { '' => [ { if => [ 'entity.archived', \"'Yes'", \"''" ] } ], -as => 'entity_archived' },
],
join => {
        entity => [ 'municipality', 'pictures', { 'entity_state' => [ 'entity_state_type', 'data_list_item' ] } ],
},
group_by => [ 'entity.id' ],
```

- Subclass the result (row) and resultset classes to add user role-based limiting conditions transparently to the application code (must have, or equivalent).

The call and the resulting query:

```
$c->model('DB::Person')->all

SELECT * FROM person WHERE owner = <user_id>
```

- ...if the user role security settings indicate user should only access his own persons.
- The security settings are read from DB on request start and specify which security conditions (separate classes) should apply to which table.
- This moves all security away from application code, where mistakes are made most often.

Which PHP library would allow us to implement this?